# Taking key/value pair from string and storing in map

Tags: c++, string, split

What is the best way to split a string in two?  I have this but can't get 'name' right as the substr doesnt allow me to set where to start from and where to finish, only where to start from and for how many characters (which is unknown to me):

```
string query = "key=value";
string key;
string value;
int positionOfEquals = query.find("=");
key = query.substr(0, positionOfEquals );
value = query.substr(positionOfEquals + 1);
```

Comment: Just realised I made a really stupid mistake.  Been a long day.  key = query.substr(0, positionOfEquals);

Comment: Is there a question remaining after this correction?

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose the question now is, is this the best approach in terms of performance and good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is a fine approach, but you still have one bug. What if there is no `'='`?

```
string query = "key=value";
string key;
string value;
int positionOfEquals = query.find("=");
key = query.substr(0, positionOfEquals );
if(positionOfEquals != string::npos)
  value = query.substr(positionOfEquals + 1);
```

Comment: To clarify for anyone who might wonder how this works: if the input string `query` is empty and/or does not contain `=`, then `key` will receive a copy of the entire string - because `find()` will return `npos`, which means 'no position' but in value terms contains the maximal possible index from `std::size_t`... and `substr()` stops after the input length (here `npos`) or at the end of the input string, whichever is first.